# Installing grunt-uglify gives strange error?

Tags: javascript, bash, gruntjs

It was running

```
npm install uglify --save-dev
```

and got

```
npm WARN grunt-css-url-replace@0.2.5 requires a peer of grunt@~0.4.5 but none was installed.
```

at this location:

[image]

What does it mean requires a  peer?  What is a peer?

Answer (score 0):

A few minutes of poking around online make it look like that's just npm3's way of telling you that that peerDependency package isn't installed. (Though this is wildly less than helpful of it.)

If you need it install it, if you don't ignore it.

Documents like [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/getting-started/installation-guide/#troubleshooting) for example.

Comment: I thought that is what npm DOES is install dependencies!  Why would it ask me how to do its job?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use it. I just spent a few minutes searching for the error.